# search feature for library management

Tags: php, mysqli

I am new to php or i can i m very new to coding . i have given with project library management by my company . i want to add the feature search in my project ..
There are two searches in my project
**1- student search-** 
   this feature will search the student n will display all the details about that particular student .
 search should be done on the category basis. like if i want to search a student on the basis of class, or may on the basis of branch , name .so first i need to select the category on what basis i want to search and then will type what i want to search. n hence the result should get displayed
**2- book search-**
   this feature will search the books we have in our database and will display all the details of the particular book 
  but here as i m having category of the book .. 
 engineering(even i engineering i have category - computer science , mechanical , electrical ) , friction book , stories book 
so i need a search category wise here..
can anybody please help me out in this to make a best search ...! will b pleased..

Comment: Please show what efforts you have made.

Comment: <?php 
include 'start.php'; 

 //This is only displayed if they have submitted the form 

 if (isset($_REQUEST['searching'==yes]))
 { 
 echo "<h2>Results</h2><p>"; 
 $field=$_REQUEST['field'];
 $find =$_REQUEST['find'];
 $find = strtoupper($find); 
 $find = strip_tags($find); 
 $find = trim ($find); 
 $u= "SELECT * FROM student WHERE upper($field) LIKE '%$find%' ";
 $v= "mysqli_query($con,$u)";

Comment: while($result = mysql_fetch_array( $v )) 
 { 
 echo $result['student_id']; 
 echo " "; 
 echo $result['name']; 
 echo "<br>"; 
 echo $result['class']; 
 echo "<br>";
 echo $result['branch']; 
 echo "<br>"; 
 echo "<br>"; 
 }

Comment: $anymatches="mysqli_num_rows($v)"; 
 if ($anymatches == 0) 
 { 
 echo "Sorry, but we can not find an entry to match your query<br><br>"; 
 } 
 else
 {//And we remind them what they searched for 
 echo "<b>Searched For:</b> " .$find; 
 } 
 if (empty($_REQUEST['find'])  ) 
 { 
 echo "<p>You forgot to enter a search term"; 
 die;
 } 
 
 }
 ?>

Comment: this what i have done to search students , but the only output i m getting is "results ". only string result that it . the code is not running

Answer (score 0):

?php include 'start.php'; //This is only displayed if they have submitted the form if (isset($_REQUEST['searching'==yes])) { echo "

### Results

"; $field=$_REQUEST['field']; $find =$_REQUEST['find']; $find = strtoupper($find); $find = strip_tags($find); $find = trim ($find); $u= "SELECT * FROM student WHERE upper($field) LIKE '%$find%' "; $v= "mysqli_query($con,$u)";
while($result = mysql_fetch_array( $v )) { echo $result['student_id']; echo " "; echo $result['name']; echo "
"; echo $result['class']; echo "
"; echo $result['branch']; echo "
"; echo "
"; }
$anymatches="mysqli_num_rows($v)"; if ($anymatches == 0) { echo "Sorry, but we can not find an entry to match your query
"; } else {//And we remind them what they searched for echo "**Searched For:** " .$find; } if (empty($_REQUEST['find']) ) { echo "

You forgot to enter a search term"; die; } } ?>